# UICollectionView only shows the last cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have an array with strings that have to be in a cell label:

```
var sounds = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

here is the code of cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    var cell: MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)

    cell.label.text = sounds[indexPath.row]
    cell.label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)
    cell.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    return cell
}
```

The problem is that when i run the app there is only one cell and it is displaying the text of the last item in the array.

I think it is not working cause in the Attribute inspector when i click the CollectionView it says that items is one 1

Is there a way to make the items number to be array.count ?

Here is where i setup the number of items:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return sounds.count
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the cell's frame?

Comment: Also, please post your other collection view delegate and data source methods. I also notice `array` isn't used in the code you posted.

Comment: I set the cell's frame to make it larger. and yeah i know it was just an exemple array i will change it

Comment: Don't set the cell's frame. Make it larger using your collection view layout object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the cell's frame. Make it larger using your collection view layout object.